# Are Spring's @Autowired object reused?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

And if they are, How to stop that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the `scope` of the `bean` being annotated.  If it is of scope `singleton`, then it the same instance will be used everywhere in the Spring `ApplicationContext`.  If it is of scope `prototype`, then a new instance will be used in each location.

```
<bean id="id" class="some.NewObject" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="id2" class="some.AnotherNewObject" scope="singleton"/>
```

These bean definitions coupled with the following code will help to illustrate.

```
class Class1 {
    @Autowired
    some.AnotherNewObject obj;
}

class Class2 {
    @Autowired
    some.AnotherNewObject obj;
}

class Class3 {
    @Autowired
    some.NewObject obj;
}

class Class4 {
    @Autowired
    some.NewObject obj;
}
```

`Class1` and `Class2` will receive a reference to the same instance of `some.AnotherNewObject`.  `Class3` and `Class4` will receive references to different instances of `some.NewObject`.

If you are using annotations and package scanning for configuration, then you can can use the `@Scope` annotation to specify your scope:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class NewObject {
    ...
}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
class AnotherNewObject {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good, but how do it change the scope in annotation?

Comment: What do you mean, can you give some more context?  You cannot change the scope of a bean using the `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: but you can change the scope with annotation on the bean itself

Answer (score 3):

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class CustomerService 
{}
```

Comment: I do not understand why prototype/singleton.// are not declared as enums by Spring.

Comment: I do agree on that post, where the answer talks about value of a page inside a Controller, but here we could use an enum for PROTOTYPE, which will be a compile time constant, the Scope annotation would take into for example an ENUM as input, not a String. For example GeneratedValue from Hibernate does that.

Comment: You cannot use an enum because `Scope`, a Spring class, is extensible.  I can define my own `Scope` and register it with Spring's `ApplicationContext`, and at that point, it can be used within Spring's `@Scope` annotation.